# Is it possible to trigger Chrome's "Rats! WebGL hit a snag" accidentally?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

From what I can tell about this message, it appears when the driver encounters an error. The implication seems to be that the JavaScript code can't trigger this warning even if there's some kind of mistake in it, because of higher-level error checking.

But my code recently triggered it, just once and I haven't been able to reproduce it (and the code — in theory at least — sends the exact same commands to WebGL every time). So I just want to know if I should be debugging my code (I can't see any obvious errors), or if I should put it down to a hardware random / browser bug.

I can post semi-reduced code on request, but it's still about half a thousand lines and I certainly don't expect people to debug it for me, hence the more general is-it-possible question.

Comment: FYI a lot of sites have this problem like SO careers or CNBC.   It happens on my Samsung s3 but not my mot  RAZR maxx hd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling a little with what your question means by "trigger". When this error occurs, javascript is always in the causal chain, because WebGL doesn't run without javascript executing it, right? So certainly it's possible to trigger the error accidentally (unless you always trigger it on purpose, which I'm sure is not the case).

However, graphics drivers are notorious for being affected by many factors that are not under programmer control or necessarily detectable by the programmer, and therefore seem non-deterministic. That's why Google recommends that you try reloading the page when the error occurs. (A link to their guidance was here, but they moved or removed the page.) I've often had Chrome successfully display some WebGL after reloading a page, when the previous attempt ended in the "snag" error. (And I know you're aware of that.)

There are certainly times when WebGL code (like the various shaders on http://shadertoy.com/) work fine on some machines and not others, and work fine one minute and not the next, on the same machine. So that suggests that the "snag" error doesn't necessarily imply that your code is at fault.

However, articles like [How to write portable WebGL](http://codeflow.org/entries/2013/feb/22/how-to-write-portable-webgl/) can help you minimize risky practices in your code, and reduce the frequency of these errors.

Comment: I suppose it is ambiguous, but what I really mean is whether I should assume my code is at fault. I'd never seen the message before so assumed it could be caused by risky practices, but since you seem to be saying it can happen to any site which uses WebGL, I'm inclined to put it down to a random glitch. Having said that, I'll certainly start debugging with the debug context utility that article links to, and I'll add some code to deal with context loss (which I don't think caused the issue but is something I wasn't aware of). Thanks.